# XSLT Grouping by n elements

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am super new in xslt and need help with a simple program.
I need to parse an xml and group the elements by next 5 elements and add a new tag.
Example:
Input xml:

```
        <element>test1</element>
        <element>test2</element>
        <element>test3</element>
        <element>test4</element>
        <element>test5</element>
        <element>test6</element>
        <element>test7</element>
        <element>test8</element>
        <element>test9</element>
        <element>test10</element>
```

Expected Output:

```
<new>
    <element>test1</element>
    <element>test2</element>
    <element>test3</element>
    <element>test4</element>
    <element>test5</element>
</new>
<new>
    <element>test6</element>
    <element>test7</element>
    <element>test8</element>
    <element>test9</element>
    <element>test10</element>
</new>
```

Comment: See the grouping in XSLT 2 section in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info, give it a try based on the examples given there, if you get stuck, show us exactly where and how.

Comment: Thanks!! This was really helpful :)